# Trying to change the ReactMapGL cursor from the default hand icon to a pointer or crosshair

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a JSX like below in my class's render method:

```
<ReactMapGL
                        ref={this.mapRef}
                        {...viewport}
                        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
                        onViewportChange={this.handleViewportChange}


                        }
                        }
 >
```

Cannot seem to find what to specify in order make the cursor be a pointer or crosshair instead of the default hand icon.

When I open it in my browser I am seeing a `<div>` element like below and its setting the cursor to "grab" and I want to able to have it be initially a different value:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 1618px; height: 272px; cursor: grab; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); outline: none;" tabindex="0">
```

Answer (score 3):

Turned out I needed to add to my ReactMapGL component this:

```
getCursor={(e) => "crosshair"}
```

Comment: `getCursor` is gone as of version 7, now it's just "cursor" - https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map#cursor  but it's still tricky to change the cursor behavior - https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/579